# Best way to use DBContext to avoid errors like The context cannot be used while the model is being created

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, dbcontext

I have this code:

```
public List<Models.MenuViewModel> Menus()
{
    using (context = new EDMX.JOBSSITE_dbEntities())
    {
        var z = context.Menus.ToList();
        var x = CreateVM(0, z);
        return x;
    }
}
```

This line

```
var z = context.Menus.ToList();
```

throws the following error sometimes

> The context cannot be used while the model is being created. This exception may be thrown if the context is used inside the OnModelCreating method or if the same context instance is accessed by multiple threads concurrently. Note that instance members of DbContext and related classes are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

What I can do to avoid this error?

**Update**: the above code is in an `ActionFilter` for ASP.NET MVC.

**Update**: I have resolved it, I have to create `using` block like this

```
using (EDMX.JOBSSITE_dbEntities context = new EDMX.JOBSSITE_dbEntities())
```

Instead of creating it like this

```
using (context = new EDMX.JOBSSITE_dbEntities())
```

Where context object get defined like

```
EDMX.JOBSSITE_dbEntities context;
```

at the top of class

But I need explanation how it worked, will be helpful for other readers

Comment: What does the context constructor (and especially the OnModelCreating method) look like?

Comment: @DevilSuichiro `public JOBSSITE_dbEntities()
            : base("name=JOBSSITE_dbEntities")
        {
        }
    
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }` But I am using database first

Comment: @DevilSuichiro I am using database first approach

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Comment: @marc_s updated